# Simple if else shell script

Tags: shell, if-statement, sh

I try to execute the file `sample.sh` using the command `sh sample.sh`, which contains the below code:

```
#!/bin/sh

a=10
b=20

if [ $a == $b ]
then
   echo "a is equal to b"
else
   echo "a is not equal to b"
fi
```

So when I try to execute I get the below error:

```
: command not foundine 2:
: command not foundine 5:
sample.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
sample.sh: line 11: `fi'
```

Can someone help me out, where am I going wrong please?

Comment: What line endings does the file have?

Comment: am very new to shell program Biffen, so can u share what line endings means

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline For a quick fix, run `dos2unix sample.sh`.

Comment: Or does it work if you use `=` instead of `==`?

Comment: if i rin dos2unix sample.sh i get below error.       -bash: dos2unix: command not found

Comment: Then you don't have `dos2unix` (surely you could understand that?).

Comment: ya i can,should i instal that in my server